# N(H)/H and the Weyl group

Tags: lie-groups, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $ H $ be a connected subgroup of $ G=\mathrm{SU}(n) $ such that $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite. Is $ N_G(H)/H $ always a subgroup of the symmetric group $ \mathrm{S}_n $?

I just noticed this from the examples

- [$ \mathrm{SU}(2) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4398724/758507)
- [$ \mathrm{SU}(3) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4535587/758507)
- [$ \mathrm{SU}(4) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535647/maximal-closed-subgroups-of-su4)
- [$ \mathrm{SU}(6) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828244/is-the-irreducible-su3-subgroup-of-su6-maximal)

In general I'm interested in the case where $ G $ is simple and $ H $ is a connected subgroup of $ G $ such that $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite. What can we say about the finite group $ N_G(H)/H $?

For $ G=\mathrm{SU}(2) $ the only nontrivial finite group $ N_G(H)/H $ is cyclic $ 2 $.

For $ G=\mathrm{SU}(3) $ the nontrivial finite groups $ N_G(H)/H $ are cyclic $ 3 $ and the symmetric group $ \mathrm{S}_3 $

For $ G=\mathrm{SO}(5) $ the only nontrivial finite $ N_G(H)/H $ are cyclic $ 2 $ and $ \mathrm{D}_4 $.

For $ G=\mathrm{G}_2 $ the only nontrivial finite groups $ N_G(H)/H $ are cyclic $ 2 $ and $ \mathrm{D}_6 $.

For $ G=\mathrm{SU}(4) $ the only nontrivial finite $ N_G(H)/H $ are cyclic $ 2 $, cyclic $ 4 $ and the symmetric group $ \mathrm{S}_4 $

For $ G=\mathrm{SU}(6) $ the finite $ N_G(H)/H $ include cyclic $ 2 $, cyclic $ 3 $ and the symmetric groups $ \mathrm{S}_3 $ and $ \mathrm{S}_6 $

In general if $ G $ is a simple Lie group and $ H $ is a subgroup such that $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite then $ N_G(H)/H $ always seems to be a subgroup of the Weyl group of $ G $ (same thing if $ G $ is a simple algebraic group). Is this true?

[cross posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828319/normalizer-of-connected-subgroup) from MSE